# Creating a dropdown in my webpage with selected entries from my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu, command-line

I am creating a webpage in which person enters a name and the marketplaces registered under that name is displayed in a dropdown. 
Here's part of my code

```
            <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="seller">Seller Name/ID</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Seller Username/ID" required>
            </li>
             <?php

             ?>
            <li>
                <label for="marketplace">Choose a marketplace</label>
                <select name="url" onchange="menu_goto(this.form)">
                <?php
                    include ('config.php');
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $query = "SELECT Marketplace FROM Details WHERE Seller_name='$username' OR Seller_ID='$username'";
                    $result = mysql_query($dbcon, $query) or die('error getting data');
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<option value="marketplace1">" . $row['Marketplace'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
            </li>
```

but when i'm running the .php file i'm getting a screen with results of till the php script is encountered, the html code below it remains untouched. I'm new with this. I'm unable to detect the error (if any) in my code. The config.php file is just a connection established with my database (no more code included in it).Also, the rest of my code works fine if i remove the php script from the code and my webpage is then displayed. I am guessing the problem is with my php script.

EDIT: I used the following answered by someone:
on username input field, put a javascript function and then use ajax to call server side code and then append result of that as option with url field. like following.

```
    <form name="login" action="index_submit" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="seller">Seller Name/ID</label>
            <input type="text" onchange="ajaxCall(this.value)" id="username" placeholder="Seller Username/ID" required>
        </li>
         <?php

         ?>
        <li>
            <label for="marketplace">Choose a marketplace</label>
            <select name="url" onchange="menu_goto(this.form)">
            </select>
        </li>
```

javascript function should be like this.

```
          <script>
           function ajaxCall(val)
            {
          $.post('abc.php',{'username':val},function(res){
           $.('#url').html(res);
           });
           }
        </script>
```

abc.php will be following.

```
                <?php
                include ('config.php');
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $query = "SELECT Marketplace FROM Details WHERE Seller_name='$username' OR Seller_ID='$username'";
                $result = mysql_query($dbcon, $query) or die('error getting data');
                $res='';
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $res .='<option value="marketplace1">' . $row['Marketplace'] . '</option>';
                }
             echo $res;
             ?>
```

and my whole code is getting executed now, but i'm still not getting any value in my dropdown list.(it appears blank and yes, i have values in my database).

Comment: Well first off you  have the parameters for `mysql_query()` the wrong way round, do `$result = mysql_query($query, $dbcon)` Or maybe you are using the MYSQLI_ extension and its just a TYPO and it should be `mysqli_query($dbcon, $query)`

Comment: Deprecated mysql* [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO

Comment: search informations about error reporting

Comment: Have a look at this for [how to use mysqli and Proper error processing](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17) Many more available on t'internet

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I'm using mysql and internchanging the $dbcon and $query aien't helping. The result is still the same.

Comment: Add the contents of your `config.php` to your question **not in a comment** the issue may well be in there **Also** have you looked at your `php error log` ??

Comment: So run the browser and open the JAVASCRIPT DEBUGGER ( Normally F12) set a breakpoint on the first line of `ajaxCall(val)`. You will then see **A** if it is running and **B** What it is doing and **C** what the `val` parameter actually contains and **D** what is being returned **if anything**

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<option value="marketplace1">" . $row['Marketplace'] . "</option>";
                    ^            ^ ---------> Not escaped
```

Try

```
echo "<option value=\"marketplace1\">" . $row['Marketplace'] . "</option>";
```

Or

```
echo '<option value="marketplace1">' . $row['Marketplace'] . '</option>';
```

Hope it helps.

PS: Take a look at MySQLi and/or PDO, because mysql functions are deprecated.

Edit: If theres no error, do u have error_reporting on? If not insert

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

into your Document and u should get something like this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'marketplace1' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index.php on line 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure what error_reporting(E_ALL) does, though adding it in my php script has made no difference. Do I need to add a submit for my php code to read the marketplaces of the username entered by the viewer?

Comment: look at your `php error log` if you are tesing this in a server setup as live chances are errors will not be displayed on the browser but might be getting logged to an error log

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have made the HTML chnages suggested by @yaso

Change your code like this, it should set errors to be displayed on the browser window.

I also assumne you are launching this with a url like

`example.com/myscript.php?username=OneThatExists`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    include ('config.php');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "SELECT Marketplace FROM Details WHERE Seller_name='$username' OR Seller_ID='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$dbcon) or die('error getting data');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value="marketplace1">" . $row['Marketplace'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

You should really be testing that a parameter was actually passed something like this. You can write the `sanityCheck()`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    include ('config.php');

    if ( isset($_POST['username']) ) {

        $_POST['username'] = sanityCheck($_POST['username']);

        $query = "SELECT Marketplace 
                  FROM Details 
                  WHERE Seller_name='{$_POST['username']' 
                     OR Seller_ID='{$_POST['username']}'";

        $result = mysql_query($query, $dbcon) or die('error getting data');

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<option value="marketplace1">" . $row['Marketplace'] . "</option>";
        }
    } else {
        // do whatever you want to do if no parameter was entered
    }
?>
```